# Apache on Windows loading broken HTML

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, html

I have the weirdest issue going on right now and I've spent my whole weekend trying to figure it out and Googling it with no success.

I setup an Apache 2.2.22 x86 server on Windows 7 from the Apache Lounge binaries. Then I installed PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5.25a.

I've completely ruled out both MySQL and PHP and come to the conclusion this is an Apache issue.

**The issue**:
Every time I do a refresh for a site/page, it is loaded differently each time with random parts of the HTML destroyed or missing.

This happens on static HTML with no scripts.

I've checked dev tools in IE, firebug in FF and dev tools in Chrome and none of them show any issues.

An example of a bad load (note: this is static HTML and not a real PHPINFO page):

[image]

As you can see, the tables are all messed up, if I reload the page, it will load different but still broken in some way and it never loads right.

This behavior is on all of my ~10 sites and if you move the sites to a working server, they all load perfectly as they should. The issue is on the server somewhere.

Any ideas?

Edit: Also, if you go into view source mode and continuously refresh, you can see the html being loaded differently every time and not like how it is in the document.

Edit2: I've completely removed PHP and MySQL and the issue still exists. I've deleted my httpd.conf file and just used the original with some minor edits to the server name so it is the most basic install without vhosts and the issue still exists. I've redownloaded and reinstalled, I've tried the x64 version and the issue still exists. This is fucked.

Edit3: Alright, more weird behavior, this ONLY happens from remote browsers. Using the browser on the server and hitting localhost loads the pages perfectly. When I load the page from any other computer, it shows all weird again. I'm hitting the IP of the server so it isn't a DNS issue either.

Edit4: I've nailed this down even further, remote browsers work, just not mine. This is a freshly installed machine with no chrome extensions or browser extensions other than firebug for the others. However, this computer I'm using is using virtualbox to host the server in a VM. I have a feeling this is messing up through the NIC and it's not actually the server.

Edit5: Installing VMware Workstation at the moment and setting up a fresh install of everything. Will update when I have it up and running. I suspect the issue is with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Issue was something to do with Virtual Box and the way it uses networking.

I have VMware Workstation setup on my host, installed Windows 7 as my guest and setup Apache and it works flawlessly.